# Ionic / How to expect a cached view to be refreshed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, ionic-framework

I'm using the latest Ionic "nighty build" version currently.

One good news with this version is the concept of [cached views](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionNavView/):

> By default views are cached to improve performance. When a view is
>   navigated away from, its element is left in the DOM, and its scope is
>   disconnected from the cycle. When navigating to a view which is
>   already cached, its scope is then reconnected, and the existing
>   element which was left in the DOM becomes the active view. This also
>   allows for scroll position of previous views to be maintained.

Interesting, so I tried it and it's really smooth.

**However, I come across a severe UX issue**:

Basically, my app is composed of 2 [tabs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionTabs/).

- TabA aims to display a load and list items.
- TabB aims to display other items.

Each one has its own navigation:  listing and showing specific items.
Obviously, the first time, data are fresh, but then, since cached => stale.

Cached views is really adapted to the "back" button from the "show" to the "list" of a specific tab.
Indeed, scroll is maintain and controllers don't need to reload => very good performance.

However, what a user wants when he clicks on a particular tab is to get a refreshed list.

I really can't find a pretty and efficient way to refresh a specific cached view regarding the clicked element.

I've got those declared **states** (showing the example for TabA):

```
        .state('tab', {
            url: "/tab",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "/tabs.tpl.html",
            controller: 'TabsCtrl'
        })

        .state('tab.tabAList', {
            url: '/items',
            views: {
                'tab-a': {
                    templateUrl: '/tabAList.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'TabACtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('tab.tabAShow', {
            url: '/tabAList/:itemId',
            views: {
                'tab-a': {
                    templateUrl: '/tabAShow.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'TabAShowCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
```

So, `tab`'s controller is the parent of `tab.tabAList` and `tab.tabAShow`.

`tabList` contains a function like:

```
$scope.reloadItems = function() {
    //...
}
```

How to trigger this function when `tabA` is clicked?
The tricky part is that `TabsCtrl` code is run just before nested `TabAList` controller is run.
I tried to involve a `$rootScope.$broadcast('reloadTheItems',...)` under the `on-select` attribute of the tab.
But the event is missed since `tabAList` hasn't run yet at the time of the event sending.

Has anyone experienced it and has a pretty solution?
I repeat, the goal is:  "**Reload a specific cached view on tab click**".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should listen to the `$ionicView.enter` event for the view for TabA.

Then do this from the `$scope`:

```
        $scope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", function( scopes, states ) {
            if( states.fromCache && states.stateName == "tab.tabAList" ) {
                reloadItems();
            }
        });
```

...or something similar...

Comment: Exactly what I've just did :) Thanks !  Is `states.fromCache` specific to Ionic?

Comment: No need for the `$rootScope`. `$scope` is enough since child ;)

Comment: As Mik378 said, you only need $scope.$on, no need for $rootScope.